# I don't know what it is. The only similar thing I found was a silversmith tool but this has a point on it and doesn't have the square thing on bottom

Tags: tools

This was in a box of wrenches I bought but I don't know what it is. The only similar thing I found was a Blacksmith/silversmith tool but this has a point on it and doesn't have the square thing on the bottom.[image]

Comment: Almost looks like it could be use as a hole gauge.

Comment: Are there any markings on it? If so, could you either transcribe them into your question or share a _focused_ picture of them?

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a tool used for home improvement, so probably offtopic here...

Comment: There are no markings on it. I tried doing searches for transfer punch but can't find anything that looks like it.

Comment: I dont know much about lathes, but is it bit for a wood lathe?

Comment: certainly not a "bit" for a lathe. Not a center either, I wouldn't think.

Answer (score 2):

Could be a transfer punch.

That is a punch designed to locate the centres of holes by fitting snugly in holes that exist already.